$3^{2x-1}=x^{9-2x}-5$ closed form solution
Im looking for help with this equation.
$3^{2x-1} = x^{9-2x}-5$
The original problem asked about solutions on the Naturals.
When I found 2 as a solution I noticed a different solution approximately 1.66
I am here because I failed to find a closed form for this second solution. My main attempt was to use Lamberts W function, but that failed because I couldn't do the necessary transformations.
I got to:
$(9^{x}+15)x^{2x-9}=3$
Any help is greatly appreciated!

WA says it's $x \approx 1.65999584929409...$ What makes you think there will be a closed form of a solution?

@MariusS.L. The main motivation here is to solve for 2 without using restricted domain. The second solution would come from that solution development that yields two. And I hope there is a way to solve this equation on R.

$x=2$ can easily be found by try and error. The values $\pm 3,\pm 2 ,\pm 1, 0$ are those you can check almost without using a pen. I do not think there is a closed form. $x \log x$ and $\log(3^{2x-1} + c)$ in one equation? No chance.

@underflow I am (almost) certain because a) the logarithm of sums is notoriously difficult to deal with and here we have three qualitatively very different terms that we only add, b) I haven't found any number on my list of "special numbers" (Wikipedia in several language versions) and c) $x=5/3$ is so close to the solution (under 1%) that the difference would likely have a name.
